# ShowWithoutActivation mysteriously not working

Tags: vb.net, forms

Have used this in other forms/apps without any difficulties. However, in this single form application, it doesn't appear to be working:

```
Imports System.IO

Public Class CPWBBackground
Dim _selectedScreenNo As Integer
Dim _screenWidth As Integer = 400
Dim _screenHeight As Integer = 300
Dim _CPWIni As New Dictionary(Of String, String)
Dim clArgs() As String = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()

Protected Overloads Overrides ReadOnly Property ShowWithoutActivation() As Boolean
    Get
        Return True
    End Get
End Property

Private Sub FromActivate() Handles Me.Activated
    MsgBox("blurp")
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    'exe [1] [2] / [3] [4]
    ' 1: ScreenNumber
    ' 2: ImgFile
    ' 3: Screen Width
    ' 4: Screen Height
    '  Me.Opacity = 0

    'TestFileExists
    If Not File.Exists(clArgs(2)) Then
        Debug.WriteLine("File doesn't exist. Closing..")
        Application.Exit()
    End If

    _selectedScreenNo = clArgs(1)

    'Set vars
    Try
        _screenWidth = Screen.AllScreens(_selectedScreenNo).Bounds.Width
        _screenHeight = Screen.AllScreens(_selectedScreenNo).Bounds.Height
        'Me.FormBorderStyle = Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None
        Me.Location = New Point(0, 0)
        If clArgs.Count > 3 Then
            If clArgs.Count < 5 Then
                'MsgBox("There should be either 2 or 4 arguments - only 3 - please check your command line.")
                Debug.WriteLine("Not enough args. Closing.")
                Application.Exit()
            Else
                _screenWidth = clArgs(3)
                _screenHeight = clArgs(4)
            End If
        End If
        Me.Size = New Size(_screenWidth, _screenHeight)
        Me.ShowInTaskbar = False

        PictureBox1.Size = New Size(_screenWidth, _screenHeight)
        Me.Location = Screen.AllScreens(_selectedScreenNo).Bounds.Location + New Point(0, 0)
        Dim fs As FileStream
        Dim FreedImage As Image
        fs = New FileStream(clArgs(2), FileMode.Open)
        FreedImage = Image.FromStream(fs)
        fs.Close()
        PictureBox1.BackgroundImage = FreedImage
        PictureBox1.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Stretch
    Catch ex As Exception
        Application.Exit()
    End Try

End Sub

Private Sub CPWBBackground_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing
    NotifyIcon1.Dispose()
End Sub

Private Sub CloseToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CloseToolStripMenuItem.Click
    Me.Close()
End Sub

End Class
```

I get "blurp" every time. 'Topmost' property in form desiginer is false. Any ideas?

Comment: Too much irrelevant code.  It is buggy, the ShowInTaskbar assignment in the Load event is already enough to prevent it from getting activated.  Crystal ball says that you are clicking on the window and thus getting it activated.  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Thanks Hans, but there was some tension between "minimal" and "complete" as I have absolutely no idea where the problem could be - thus difficult to reduce to an abridged/distilled example. And no, it's not my clicking on the form. The form is activated without any user interaction. Also, I am trying to achieve the form not being activated, not activated.

Answer (score 1):

Well, that was random. The solution was to add `me.hide` to the top of the me.load event.

Final working code (with some other bits tidied up):

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Me.Hide()

    'exe [1] [2] / [3] [4]
    ' 1: ScreenNumber
    ' 2: ImgFile
    ' 3: Screen Width
    ' 4: Screen Height

    If Not File.Exists(clArgs(2)) Then
        Debug.WriteLine("File doesn't exist. Closing..")
        Application.Exit()
    End If

    _selectedScreenNo = clArgs(1)

    _screenWidth = Screen.AllScreens(_selectedScreenNo).Bounds.Width
    _screenHeight = Screen.AllScreens(_selectedScreenNo).Bounds.Height
    Me.Location = Screen.AllScreens(_selectedScreenNo).Bounds.Location + New Point(0, 0)
    If clArgs.Count > 3 Then
        If clArgs.Count < 5 Then
            Debug.WriteLine("Not enough args. Closing.")
            Application.Exit()
        Else
            _screenWidth = clArgs(3)
            _screenHeight = clArgs(4)
        End If
    End If
    Me.Size = New Size(_screenWidth, _screenHeight)

    Dim fs As FileStream
    Dim FreedImage As Image
    fs = New FileStream(clArgs(2), FileMode.Open)
    FreedImage = Image.FromStream(fs)
    fs.Close()

    Me.BackgroundImage = FreedImage
    Me.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Stretch

End Sub
```